# Prevent Chrome (and other) Browsers Rememeber Scroll Position on Page Load

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, browser, scroll

I'm pulling hair out here. Chrome has an annoying habit of remembering page scroll position when you load a previously viewed page. This is very undesired for my webapp, but whatever I try I cannot prevent Chrome from doing this. My testing environment is on a Linux Ubuntu virtual box with Chrome. I've developed one hack that waits about 600ms after page load before manually setting scroll position to top of page, but this makes page load times seem 600ms longer then they have to be which sucks. here is my hack that works

```
// hide the whole document, then show it after delay
$('#iContainer').addClass('cDispHide')
setTimeout(function(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    $('#iContainer').removeClass('cDispHide');
}, 600 );
```

After doing some research online here is everything i tried

1. I put this in script tags right before including jQuery

   ```
   if ('scrollRestoration' in history) {
       history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
   }
   ```

On chrome its supposed to disable this scroll memory behaviour, but it does not, has no impact. Maybe i'm putting it in the wrong place?

2. put this in unload:

   ```
   window.addEventListener('unload', function(e){
       document.body.style.display = 'none';
   });
   ```

which is supposed to disable this behaviour, but it does not. I've place this code inside jquery $(window).load() function and it has no effect. I've also tried setting window.scrollTo(0, 0) in on unload as well with no effect

3. I've tried putting

   ```
   document.location = "#";
   ```

inside $(window).load() and $(document).ready() which is supposed to tell the browser to load at top of page, but it has no effect, despite placing the '#' in my address bar

4. I've tried manually setting window.scrollTo(0, 0) before doing any ajax that leads me away from the current page, which still has no impact upon returning to the page. Basically the page scrolls to top of page, does ajax, leaves the page, and when I return to the page I'm sent to the middle of the page as my remembered scroll position!?!?!? how does this make any sense. Its like my setting window.scrollTo() has no impact on what Chrome is remembering as my scroll position.

I've even noticed that if i scroll to the top of the page with the mouse, then leave the page, then return to it, its taking me to some point in the middle of the page for some reason. It's not remembering my scroll to the top, its like its remembering some previous scroll position from long ago. There is nothing in my code thats making it do this.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Argh

Ok sorry, despite my claim i was not setting the page, it was buried deep in some old code and is actually being done in some external library I'm using, so it was very hard to detect, but upon listening to my own question the fact it seemed to be remembering by something else got me looking even harder, and yes indeed it was being manually set to a position.

Once i resolved this, simply adding

$(html,body).scrollTop(0)

in document load worked. it does need a very brief timeout like 20ms. Also you can set scroll position on leaving a page to 0 if you want that to be remembered as well. thanks everyone who considered my Q